# object doesnot initiates when object is passed by refrence in php

Tags: php

I want to pass object by refrence but it dont give proper result 
This is I have already tried

```
<?php
class my_class
{
var $my_var;
function my_class ($var)
{
global $obj_instance;
$obj_instance = &$this;
$this->my_var = $var;
}
}
$obj = new my_class ("something");
echo $obj->my_var."\n";
echo $obj_instance->my_var;
?>
```

output :
something

Expected result : 
something
something

Comment: Be aware that since PHP 5.3.3 class-named constructors are treated as regular methods in favor of `__construct()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At PHP Manual in "[What References Do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)" page, you can read:

> If you assign a reference to a variable declared global inside a
>   function, the reference will be visible only inside the function. You
>   can avoid this by using the $GLOBALS array.

Example:

```
<?php
$var1 = "Example variable";
$var2 = "";

function global_references($use_globals)
{
    global $var1, $var2;
    if (!$use_globals) {
        $var2 =& $var1; // visible only inside the function
    } else {
        $GLOBALS["var2"] =& $var1; // visible also in global context
    }
}

global_references(false);
echo "var2 is set to '$var2'\n"; // var2 is set to ''
global_references(true);
echo "var2 is set to '$var2'\n"; // var2 is set to 'Example variable'
?>
```

From PHP.net